# How to create last activity logger?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

I created an application in node.js similar to Jira, and I would like to add functionality that shows on the user interface the last actions performed on a given board, but I don't know how to go about it.

Should I call a function that would save the action to the database at each request, or are there better solutions for this situation?

Comment: I would think that storing data in a database sounds reasonable. If you have a more specific question perhaps you would like to share some of your code.

Comment: Storing logs in database is the best solution as @MikePoole said.